# Perl Connection String for MS Access Professional Plus 2019

Tags: sql, perl, ms-access, dbi

I have a Perl script which used this connection string to write to an MS Access DB.  It worked for Microsoft 365:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=$cwd/imperial.accdb", '', '');
```

That no longer works with  Professional Plus 2019.  Anyone know what I should use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The short issue and story is simply that with Access 2019 (and 2016)
> CTR (click to run - which is most installations,then installing Access
> does not expose a registered copy of ACE).
>
> [...]
>
> So, you need to install the ACE data engine (not access).
> Installing ACE from here should do the trick:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44f542b1-a24a-4fbb-8788-f62c28e2ffac/office-2019-connection-string?forum=accessdev)